# How to interpret log outcomes in a linear regression?

Tags: linear-regression, transformation, logarithm

Because my data is not normally distributed, I performed log transformation on my datasets. Subsequently, I carried out a linear regression between the 2 transformed datasetss using the *log1p* function in R.
Let's say the beta coefficient of the linear regression model is 0.03; how do I interpret this result (because this result was influenced by the log1p-transformation)? Does this indicate that my real result is 10^(0.03+1) = 10.72?